# Docker swarm - add new worker - re scale the service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have created a docker manager. Created a service and scaled to 5 instances in the same server.

I added two workers. Now, How do I redistribute 5 instances of the applications across 3 nodes?

Is there any option to do without doing everything from the beginning?

`docker service scale id=5` does it. Is it the right way? I don't want to restart already existing instances. It restarts at node 1.

`docker service update servicename`

I remove one node from the cluster by `docker swarm leave`. I updated the service. All of my instances are replicated within remaining nodes.

Glad, Update worked as expected. But, there is another twist.

I added the node back. Then I updated the service. Now, all of my instances are running as in the earlier case. It doesn't make use of the new node.

How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redistribute, you don't need to destroy and recreate the service, but the containers will all be bounced in a rolling upgrade. The command is `docker service update --force $service_name`

---

When adding or removing nodes, docker will only reschedule when there is a difference between the current and target state. It doesn't prematurely kill running containers to reschedule then on new nodes until you do the above update command.

Comment: Final clarification, What do you mean by current and target state? Is it related to image or service? `It doesn't prematurely kill running containers to reschedule then on new nodes until you do the above update command` mean if I run `--force update`, it will kill running containers and reschedule to ensure HA. Am I right?

Comment: The force update will do a rolling update of the service, restarting containers, and rebalancing them. Current state is whatever is running now, target state is the definition in the service.